# How do I adjust my code to access the original member and not a copy of it?

Tags: c++, list

I have a class called Child that holds a name and a list of string items. Different child objects are stored in a separate list, sort of as a nested list. The representation is:

List<"Child"> [Child1(name, List<"string">), Child2(name, List<"string">), etc.]

My objective is to create two functions: `insertChild()` and `insertPresent()`. The first one works, where the idea is to insert a child object into List(Child) with a specified name and List<"string">. Where I'm having trouble is with `insertPresent()`, where it is supposed to search List<"Child"> given a name and, once there's a match, add a present (string) to that Child object's List<"string">.

The problem appears to be I'm accessing a local copy of the List<"string"> when calling `getList()`, which explains why there appears to be no errors and the original list remains untouched after calling `insertPresent()`. How do I implement the changes to access the original list and not the copy? Here's the code:

ArrayList.h:

```
template<class ItemType>
class ArrayList
{
private:
    static const int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 5; // Small capacity to test for a full list 
    ItemType items[DEFAULT_CAPACITY];      // Array of list items
protected:
    int itemCount;                         // Current count of list items 
    int maxItems;                          // Maximum capacity of the list
    
public:
   ArrayList();
   // Copy constructor and destructor are supplied by compiler
   
   bool isEmpty() const;
   int getLength() const;
   bool insert(int newPosition, const ItemType& newEntry);
   bool remove(int position);
   void clear();
   
   /** @throw PrecondViolatedExcep if position < 1 or 
                                      position > getLength(). */
   ItemType getEntry(int position) const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);

   /** @throw PrecondViolatedExcep if position < 1 or 
                                      position > getLength(). */
   void setEntry(int position, const ItemType& newEntry) throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
}; // end ArrayList

template<class ItemType>
ArrayList<ItemType>::ArrayList() : itemCount(0), maxItems(DEFAULT_CAPACITY)
{
}  // end default constructor

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayList<ItemType>::isEmpty() const
{
    return itemCount == 0;
}  // end isEmpty

template<class ItemType>
int ArrayList<ItemType>::getLength() const
{
    return itemCount;
}  // end getLength

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayList<ItemType>::insert(int newPosition, const ItemType& newEntry)
{
    bool ableToInsert = (newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= itemCount + 1) &&
        (itemCount < maxItems);
    if (ableToInsert)
    {
        // Make room for new entry by shifting all entries at
        // positions >= newPosition toward the end of the array
        // (no shift if newPosition == itemCount + 1)
        for (int pos = itemCount; pos >= newPosition; pos--)
            items[pos] = items[pos - 1];

        // Insert new entry
        items[newPosition - 1] = newEntry;
        itemCount++;  // Increase count of entries
    }  // end if

    return ableToInsert;
}  // end insert

template<class ItemType>
bool ArrayList<ItemType>::remove(int position)
{
    bool ableToRemove = (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount);
    if (ableToRemove)
    {
        // Remove entry by shifting all entries after the one at
        // position toward the beginning of the array
        // (no shift if position == itemCount)
        for (int fromIndex = position, toIndex = fromIndex - 1; fromIndex < itemCount;
            fromIndex++, toIndex++)
            items[toIndex] = items[fromIndex];

        itemCount--;  // Decrease count of entries
    }  // end if

    return ableToRemove;
}  // end remove

template<class ItemType>
void ArrayList<ItemType>::clear()
{
    itemCount = 0;
}  // end clear

template<class ItemType>
ItemType ArrayList<ItemType>::getEntry(int position) const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep)
{
    // Enforce precondition
    bool ableToGet = (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount);
    if (ableToGet)
        return items[position - 1];
    else
    {
        string message = "getEntry() called with an empty list or ";
        message = message + "invalid position.";
        throw(PrecondViolatedExcep(message));
    }  // end if
}  // end getEntry

template<class ItemType>
void ArrayList<ItemType>::setEntry(int position, const ItemType& newEntry) throw(PrecondViolatedExcep)
{
    // Enforce precondition
    bool ableToSet = (position >= 1) && (position <= itemCount);
    if (ableToSet)
        items[position - 1] = newEntry;
    else
    {
        string message = "setEntry() called with an empty list or ";
        message = message + "invalid position.";
        throw(PrecondViolatedExcep(message));
    }  // end if
}  // end setEntry
```

Child.h:

```
#include "ArrayList.h"

class Child
{
private:
    string name;
    ArrayList<string> presents;

public:
    string getName() const;
    ArrayList<string> getList() const;
    void setName(string name);
    void setList(ArrayList<string> aList);
};

string Child::getName() const {
    return name;
}

ArrayList<string> Child::getList() const {
    return presents;
}

void Child::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Child::setList(ArrayList<string> aList) {
    this->presents = aList;
}
```

NiceArrayList.h: List<"Child">

```
#include <string>
#include "Child.h"
using namespace std;

template<class ItemType>
class NiceArrayList : public ArrayList<ItemType>
{
public:
    /** Inserts an object containing name and aList into this list at a given position.
    @pre  None.
    @post  If 1 <= position <= getLength() + 1 and the insertion is
       successful, name and aList is at the given position in the nice list,
       other entries are renumbered accordingly, and the returned
       value is true.
    @param position  The list position at which to insert the object.
    @param name  The string assigned to the object inserted into this list.
    @param aList  The list assigned to the object inserted into this list.
    @return  True if insertion is successful, or false if not. */
    bool insertChild(int position, string name, const ArrayList<string>& aList);

    /** Inserts a new entry to the gift list inside an object from this
        list given a name.
    @pre  The parameter name must be in an object in this list.
    @post  If 1 <= position <= getLength() + 1 and the insertion is
       successful, newEntry is at the given position in the gift list,
       other entries are renumbered accordingly, and the returned
       value is true.
    @param position  Theobject list position at which to insert the new entry.
    @param name  The string used to identify the object in this list.
    @param newEntry  The entry to insert into the object's list.
    @return  True if removal is successful, or false if not. */
    bool insertPresent(string name, string newEntry);
};

template<class ItemType>
bool NiceArrayList<ItemType>::insertChild(int position, string name, const ArrayList<string>& aList) {
    bool ableToInsert = false;
    Child aChild;
    aChild.setName(name);
    aChild.setList(aList);
    ableToInsert = this->insert(position, aChild);
    return ableToInsert;
}

template<class ItemType>
bool NiceArrayList<ItemType>::insertPresent(string name, string newEntry) {
    bool ableToInsert = false;
    int length = this->getLength();
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        position++;
        if (this->getEntry(i).getName() == name) {
            break;
        }
    }
    //THE PROBLEM APPEARS TO BE HERE! THE INSERT DOES NOT UPDATE THE LIST!
    ableToInsert = this->getEntry(position).getList().insert(1, newEntry);
    return ableToInsert;
}
```

Sample main to test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "NiceArrayList.h"

int main() {

    ArrayList<string> aList1;
    aList1.insert(1, "PS4");
    aList1.insert(2, "PS5");
    aList1.insert(3, "Toy Car");

    NiceArrayList<Child> nice;
    nice.insertChild(1, "John", aList1);
    nice.insertPresent("John", "Phone");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You've got a rather complex setup. Did you test simpler pieces first? For example, start with `ArrayList<string>` (like your `aList1`) then try to modify an element of that? Something like `aList1.getEntry(1) = "New thing";`?

Comment: @JaMiT Yessir, everything works as expected. I realize everything looks complicated than it should, but all of it works except for that one function I mentioned. Just so you get an idea, `insertPresent()` is calling `insert()` and it returns true as if it worked, however the list's `itemCount` does not update.

Comment: Try your tests again, because not everything works as expected. Starting with your example, I replaced the three lines that use `nice` with `std::cout << aList1.getEntry(1); aList1.getEntry(1) = "New thing"; std::cout << aList1.getEntry(1);` (and eliminated the two now-unneeded headers). My expected output is `PS4New thing`, but the actual output is `PS4PS4`.

Comment: That's not what supposed to happen, what you got was expected. The only way to replace an entry in the list is to use `setEntry()`. The way you tried to alter it will  not work.

Comment: *"The only way to replace an entry in the list is to use `setEntry()`."* -- Well, I'd call it "change" instead of "replace" (it's the same `string` object, just with different data), but OK, that is another reasonable paradigm. In that case, the only way for `insertPresent()` to change an entry in the list (a.k.a. `*this`) is to use `setEntry()` -- where does this happen?

Comment: Hmm... if you don't agree that "replace" means "change" in this context, I would suggest a similar test as I suggested earlier, but this time try to downgrade the gift to a PS3 with the line `aList1.getEntry(1)[2] = '3';`. This version does not replace the entire string, right, just a piece? And yet, it fails to make a lasting change.

Comment: Okay so I'm not trying to replace or change anything. `insertPresent()` is supposed to add a new entry to the list in the Child object from the NiceArrayList list. This should work with `insert()` (as used in the definition for `insertPresent()`).

Comment: You realize that adding a new entry to a list is a change to the list, right? (You want to *change* the list from `"PS4", "PS5", "Toy Car"` to `"PS4", "PS5", "Toy Car", "Phone"`.) So you **are** changing something. You are trying to change "the list in the Child object from the NiceArrayList list", which implies changing "the Child object from the NiceArrayList list", which is the thing you cannot change without calling `setEntry()`.

Comment: I apologize for the technicality of word choice, so let's try this again. `setEntry()` is meant to **replace** an entry in a list while `insert()` adds a new entry to the list, so to make you happy it **changes** the list by adding to it. I want to add to the list, which is only attainable by using the `insert()` method.

Comment: It's more a question of focus than word choice. *There is more than one list.* Look at the line `this->getEntry(position).getList().insert(1, newEntry);`. You are focusing on the list returned by `getList()`. I am looking at the list returned by `this->`. You call `insert` to add an element to the child's `presents` array. This is a change to the `presents` array. This is a change to a `Child` object. In order to change a `Child` object in `*this`, your paradigm requires a call to `this->setEntry()`. The missing call is not to `this->getEntry(position).setEntry()`, but to `this->setEntry()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here

```
ArrayList<string> Child::getList()  const {
    return presents;
}
```

This is returning a copy of presents, So thios line only updates the copy

```
ableToInsert = this->getEntry(position).getList().insert(1, newEntry);
```

You need

```
ArrayList<string> & Child::getList()   {
    return presents;
}
```

Note the removal of the const too

and here

```
ArrayList<string> &getList() ;
```

same for getEntry on ArrayList, same fix

Comment: I totally agree the problem is that I'm accessing a copy of the list through `getList()` however your suggestion did not seem to work. Any other ideas?

Comment: @kirito23 getEntry also returns a copy, same fix

Comment: Is there another way around applying that to `getList()`? Or if I can make other adjustments to Child like turning `presents` into a pointer that points to the sublist I'm trying to change?

Comment: @kirito23 just make getList return a reference too

Comment: I fixed it! I applied the insertion of & from your answer, kept the const, I didn't touch `getEntry()`, and instead I turned the presents attribute in Child into a pointer

Answer (score 0):

The API you defined for `ArrayList` does provide the basic operations of adding items, removing items, and changing items. However, the paradigm you chose for changing items can be awkward to use and – as you discovered – easy to mess up. It is not wrong, per se, since it is a good choice in some situations, but it does not appear to bring any of its benefits to your situation.

Since it is a valid approach, I will go over how to fix the code using the existing paradigm before going over an alternative paradigm.

### Your way

Under your approach, changing an element of a list requires calling `setEntry()`. You are not allowed to directly change an element, but must make a copy (obtained via `getEntry()`), modify the copy, then update the list with `setEntry()`.

Let us look at the line where you try to make your change.

```cpp
    ableToInsert = this->getEntry(position).getList().insert(1, newEntry);
```

This follows two of the three steps for making a change. There is a call to `this->getEntry(position)` to make a copy of the `Child` object. Then there is a change made to that copy (via `.getList().insert(1, newEntry)`), but the changed object is never given to the `NiceArrayList` as an update.

To update an element with your paradigm, you need to add a call to `setEntry()`. Given how your API is configured, this necessitates defining additional variables to help out. (Note, though, that even if this was not necessary, defining at least one of these variables would probably be a good idea style-wise, since this line is already quite long, and we intend to add code.)

```cpp
    // The first three lines split the existing line into pieces.
    ItemType toChange = this->getEntry(position);
    auto theList = toChange.getList();
    ableToInsert = theList.insert(1, newEntry);
    // The next lines update the child and list.
    toChange.setList(theList);
    this->setEntry(position, toChange);
```

Inserting an element into the `presents` list (a.k.a. `getList()`) is a change to that list, which in turn is a change to the `Child` object (a.k.a. `ItemType`). This new call to `setEntry()` replaces the object in the list with the changed copy.

### Alternative way

The line of code you used to try to update the presents list would be correct if you adopt a different paradigm for changing a list. Instead of requiring a get/set pair of function calls, you could allow direct access to the elements of an `ArrayList`, similar to how `[]` allows direct access to the elements of an array. Instead of having `getEntry()` return a *copy* of an entry, it could return a reference to the entry.

If you adopt this paradigm, you could replace the `setEntry()` function with a non-`const` version of `getEntry()`. This would change code that changes entries in an `ArrayList` from something like `setEntry(i, object);` to something like `getEntry(i) = object;`. In more complex cases, you could modify an entry directly, much like you attempted to do in your version of `insertPresent()`.

The new signature of your "get" function would look like the following.

```cpp
    const ItemType & getEntry(int position) const throw(PrecondViolatedExcep);
//  ^^^^^          ^
```

Other than this change to the return type, the implementation would remain the same. (Well, you might want to get rid of `throw(PrecondViolatedExcep)`, as that syntax was deprecated in C++11 and removed in C++17.)

The non-`const` version of this function could piggy-back on the `const` version's functionality.

```cpp
    ItemType & getEntry(int position) {
        // Trick to invoke the const version of this function:
        auto constThis = const_cast<const ArrayList *>(this);
        return const_cast<ItemType &>(constThis->getEntry(position));
    }
```

(Don't forget that you can remove `setEntry()` once this is defined. This can be a net reduction in lines of code.) This approach tends to be more intuitive to work with and less prone to bugs when used.

A similar change should be made to `Child::getList()` and `Child::setList()`. With these changes, your version of `insertPresent()` should work as-is, and you may find that working with these "get" functions is more intuitive than your original approach.

Comment: Seeing the way you would solve it using my paradigm opened my rather close-minded approach to wanting to change the `presents` list using my methods the way they are defined, you showed me how I could've taken advantage of the `senEntry()` rather than going straight for the `insert()` to try and force the original list to change

Comment: I'm still learning, so I was using a Data Structures book from 2013 that defined `ArrayList` and I wanted to use inheritance, thereby avoiding any changes to `ArrayList` directly, even if changing it would've made my life easier

Answer (score -1):

`getList()` was returning a copy of the sublist, so I turned the `presents` attribute into a pointer of the list array and made `getList()` return a reference to the array. Updated Child class:

Child.h:

```
#include "ArrayList.h"

class Child
{
private:
    string name;
    ArrayList<string>* presents;

public:
    
    string getName() const;
    ArrayList<string>& getList() const;
    void setName(string name);
    void setList(ArrayList<string>& aList);
};

string Child::getName() const {
    return name;
}

ArrayList<string>& Child::getList() const{
    return *presents;
}

void Child::setName(string name) {
    this->name = name;
}

void Child::setList(ArrayList<string>& aList) {
    this->presents = &aList;
}
```

Comment: First problem: you do not initialize `presents`. This was not a problem when `presents` was a class with a reasonable default constructor, but it is a problem for a raw pointer. What happens if someone calls `getList` before `setList` has been called? You end up de-referencing a garbage pointer. You could initialize `presents` to `nullptr`, but then you also have to figure out what `getList` should do if `presents` is null.

Comment: Second problem: this version of `setList` is likely to result in a dangling pointer. Your current example code won't produce a dangling pointer, but it is likely to happen in more complex scenarios. You have no way to ensure that the parameter to `setList` will live at least as long as the `Child` object.

Comment: I suppose both problems could be mostly solved by using a `std::shared_ptr<ArrayList<string>>` instead of a raw pointer, but that seems needlessly complicated in your scenario. You could try it, but at some point you should assess the pros and cons of this approach when compared to other approaches. I suspect the cons will heavily outweigh the pros.